# VBA Split string and convert to Int

Tags: vba, excel, split

I have an Excel sheet where I have data in a column J4:J163, Each cell contains a string e.g. J4 = "1 6, 8 18, 20 24"

Using VBA I want to use the Split function to separate on the delimiter ','
then convert string values e.g. "1 6, 8 18, 20 24" into integers. Which should result into something like this '1 6' '8 18' '20 24'

I want to iterate through each two integer values subtracting like so

1-6 = 5

8-18 = 10

20-24 = 4

Each time adding these results to a variable i.e. 'total'

Depending on how many subtractions have been performed increment a variable, cnt++, in this case 3 times, (total + cnt).

total = 22

This result calculated from cell J4 i.e. 22 should be inputted into L4. 
The result from J5 should be inputted into L5 etc.

Hope this makes sense.
Below is a very bare pseudo code, (newbie to VBA) your guidance would be well received.

```
Sub CalcHrs()

'Variables
Dim wrdArray() As String
Dim textString As String
Dim total As Integer 'substration results accumulation
Dim cnt As Integer 'for loop iteration count

' Grab String
textString = Range("J4")
' Place string into Array and Split
wrdArray() = Split(textString)

'Loop to convert string array to int array

'Some loop (i < array.length, bla bla)
'array index 0 - array index 1 place result into 'total'
'iterate through until length of array is reached, while cnt++

'place result of total + cnt into cell "L4"

'Move onto cell "J5" until "J163"
```

End Sub

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: `'1 6' '8 18' '20 24'` are not integers, they are strings that just happen to look like integers. Your post does actually make sense, but this isn't a free 'write-my-code' service, if you want help show us your code.

Comment: 1-6 is not 5, it is -5, are you looking for difference or is that a typo? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--PT3b2s322TEhwTlptakZQTWM/view?usp=sharing here is something with no VBA that gives almost what you ask for i used the Text to columns function to split out the results

Answer (score 2):

Like somebody writted up. It's not a free "write-my-code" service, You should try yourself and If your code doesn't work then You can post it here to get help.

I will give you some tips:

- Split the cell value like this: Split (Cell, ",")
- Iterate the array result of this Split with for-each and split each value like this: Split(value, " ")
- Add 1 to the normal count and add ABS(cint(value1) - cint(value2)) to the total count. Value1 and Value2 are the values retorned by the second split.